# Bulkified Trigger - Review

Tags: trigger, bulkification

Can a few people give this a look over and see if I am properly bulkifying this trigger? It is a simple trigger designed to update the Name field on other records that lookup to these records.

```
trigger Employee on Employees__c (after update) {

    Set<Employees__c>           emps        = new Set<Employees__c>();
    List<Employee_Session__c>   sessions    = new list<Employee_Session__c>();

    for(Employees__c e:trigger.new){
        //Check if HBS ID (Name) has changed. 
        if( Trigger.oldMap.get(e.Id).Name != Trigger.newMap.get(e.Id).Name ){
            //Add employee to set if not already in set. Safety in case the Employee is passed multiple times. 
            if(!emps.contains(e)){
                emps.add(e);
            }
        }   
    }

    If(emps.size()>0){
        //Find sessions for those HBS IDs that have changed. 
        Sessions = [Select ID,Name,Employee__r.Name,Session_Date__c 
                     FROM Employee_Session__c 
                     WHERE Employee__c IN :emps];

        if(sessions.size()>0){
            //Generate new name for affected sessions.
            for(Employee_Session__c es:sessions){
                es.name = es.Employee__r.Name + ' ' + es.Session_Date__c.format();
            }
            //Push Update
            update sessions;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work? Shouldn't this be `emps.add(e.ID);`?

Comment: After doing some tests that would of works the way you have it, I didn't know soql could figure out what you were sending it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is bulk-safe, but overly complicated. Many of the "if" statements you have in the code are not necessary.

```
trigger Employee on Employees__c (after update) {

    Set<Employees__c>           emps        = new Set<Employees__c>();

    for(Employees__c e:trigger.new){
        //Check if HBS ID (Name) has changed. 
        if( Trigger.oldMap.get(e.Id).Name != Trigger.newMap.get(e.Id).Name ){
            emps.add(e);
        }   
    }

    If(emps.size()>0){
        //Find sessions for those HBS IDs that have changed. 
        List<Employee_Session__c>   sessions = [Select ID,Name,Employee__r.Name,Session_Date__c 
                     FROM Employee_Session__c 
                     WHERE Employee__c IN :emps];

        //Generate new name for affected sessions.
        for(Employee_Session__c es:sessions){
            es.name = es.Employee__r.Name + ' ' + (es.Session_Date__c == null? '': es.Session_Date__c.format());
        }
        //Push Update
        update sessions;
    }
}
```

Comment: will the SOQl query work with the employee set? I assume that when I specified Employee__c IN :emps that SOQl is smart enough to look at the ID value in the set.

Comment: It should @MattM, but in this case you don't need an entire Set of Employees and you just their ID's so you don't actually need to have Set<Employee__c>.   It will save you some memory, by just having Set<ID>.. I commented above about what I said at first

Comment: @EricSSH The memory used is irrelevant, because both will store only references to the actual objects.

Comment: @MattM Yes, feel free to use Set if you want to, but using a List of Id would require less CPU time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty good, you're trying to update Employee Sessions when the Employee name changes right?

```
trigger Employee on Employees__c (after update) {

    Set<ID> empsID = new Set<ID>();
    List<Employee_Session__c> sessions = new List<Employee_Session__c>();

    for(Employees__c e: Trigger.new)
    {
        //Check if HBS ID (Name) has changed. 
        if(trigger.oldMap.get(e.Id).Name != Trigger.newMap.get(e.Id).Name )
        {
            //Add employee to set if not already in set. Safety in case the Employee is passed multiple times. 
            //Sets are unique, so the id will on exsist once
            empsID.add(e.ID);
        }   
    }

    if(empsID.size()>0)
    {
            //Generate new name for affected sessions.
        for(Employee_Session__c es : [Select ID, Name, Employee__r.Name, Session_Date__c FROM Employee_Session__c WHERE Employee__c IN :empsID])
        {
            es.Name = es.Employee__r.Name + ' ' + es.Session_Date__c.format();
            sessions.add(es);
        }
        //Push Update
        update sessions;  
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(sessions.isEmpty())` is an outdated, unnecessary guard condition.